# php/laravel - select other table's column using the belongsToMany of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code on patient model:

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'PatientID';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vaccine', 'immunizations', 'patient_id', 'vaccine_id');
    }
}
```

and this is my query

```
$patients = Patient::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($q) use ($vaccine_id) {
    $q->where('vaccine_id', '=', $vaccine_id);
})->get();
```

In my current situation I can only get the Patient model column data but not the other tables. Where should I put the `select()` method to select the rows and columns of the immunizations table because i want to set a chain `where()`or condition which is `where('immunizations_id', 1)` but it doesn't work because the immunizations table is not selected.

or does anyone here knows how to convert it without using a closure like make it

`Patient::wheredoesnthave(join('table'));` so i can freely manipulate it

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up for immunizations?

Comment: I think the  $this->belongsToMany sets the relationship

Answer (score 0):

We will get other relationship table using 'with()'

```
$patients = Patient::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($q) use ($vaccine_id) {
    $q->where('vaccine_id', '=', $vaccine_id);
    $q->with('Vaccine', 'immunizations');
})->get();
```

Try this.

Comment: what if i want to count them?

Comment: For getting the count we can use count() instead of get().